# Toggling NSVisualEffectViews (Vibrancy) off based on user preference

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Inside my main storyboard I have a NSVisualEffectView which contains a view-based NSTableView as a source list. The user can choose dark vibrancy/light vibrancy or choose to turn it off completely using a NSPopupButton. I'm using the appearance property (NSAppearance) to toggle between light/dark with material set to auto, but can't figure out how to basically turn off vibrancy without having to sub-out the NSVisualEffectView parent.

Comment: What is the question exactly ? From what you wrote I understood that you can already get the value of whether the user wants to have reduced transparency effects. Based on the value you either do or don't apply special effects.

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

For opaque:
set the `NSVisualEffectView` state to `NSVisualEffectStateInactive` with appearance set to `[NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameVibrantLight]`

For vibrancy:
state to `NSVisualEffectStateFollowsWindowActiveState` and appearance to `[NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameVibrantLight]`